# Delete shapes with specific color

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I tried creating VBA to delete shapes with specific color from all slides. But after I run those it delete all the shapes on slide. Does someone perhaps have an idea?

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    TotalShapes = sld.Shapes.Count

    For i = TotalShapes to 1 step -1 

        sld.Shapes(i).Delete

    Next

Next
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's pretty hard to see where you went wrong.  I'm guessing it's not checking the colour, or is checking the wrong colour.  Could you add your code to the question - the Edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of your post.

Comment: You are missing an If statement that checks the color.

Answer (score 0):

Slides and shapes are held in a collection so you can use `For...Each` to step through each item in the collection.
You then need to check the colour of each shape before deleting it.

This will delete red shapes:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            'Debug.Print shp.Name & ": " & shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                shp.Delete
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful!